# QGIS - Dropdown list for multi-select value-relation widget

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, valuerelation

Some fields in my project are currently configured using the value-relation widget. While everything is functioning correctly, my colleagues and I are used to working with the attribute table, row by row (instead of using the form).

The current organization of values in the multi-select value-relation widget is impractical and annoying. For each row, the available choices are not clearly visible until we adjust the length and width of the row

1[image: Ex1]

2[image: Ex2]

**I'm wondering if there is a solution to display the values more efficiently. For instance, using a dropdown list for better usability?**

For example, something like this : A dropdown list, with all the choices and their little boxes.

[image: example]